# Google Compute Engine; Node.js; http post to Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have run into something really weird that I can't figure out and I hope to gain some insight here.

The setup ... GCE is running a Node.js app (I wrote this code). It uses the popular node.js requests open source project. The simplified issue that I have setup involves this app, running as an http server, posting to another server (hhtp post) which happens to be a GAE app, when a certain url is hit. This app has been running for months just fine.

What I am suddenly observing is this. I instruct the node server to post a simple form like submission to the gae server. The request is handled by the node.js work queue, the http post is asynchronously put back on the queue. The original request returns very quickly. The async post to GAE has some veyr large latency (minutes) and then finally the request turns up at GAE and GAE says it handles it quickly (milliseconds). This latency just started happening yesterday. There is no indication that the node.js server is very busy, also the GAE server/system handles requests all the time and is very fast. It is as if either an outbound queue on the GCE side, or an inbound queue on the GAE is specifically jamming up just these requests. I should add other http posts to GAE do not show this latency and other http requests from the GCE server do not show this latency.

Any thoughts? I don't know where to turn to track this down. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you without more detail on what the node.js side is doing. How does your work-queue operate?

Comment: Yeah, I was running out of characters ...
The simplified server I have deployed is using express as a web server. The work queue I refer to is just the internal node.js queue, I am not doing anything explicit with it.
http request comes in; async http post goes to GAE; the original http request returns immediately (as it should); I see the http post handled by gae minutes later though it sees it as having just come in.